# Configurando Múltiplos Bancos de Dados no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

Minha aplicação possui conexão com um banco de dados remoto (SQLServer), mas gostaria de realizar uma pequena duplicação de certos dados menos voláteis em um banco local e embarcado (H2) para ganhar em termos de desempenho. Minha configuração hoje é a de um único banco, informando no .properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://****:1433;databaseName=****
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
```

Ficando a cargo do próprio Spring Boot a criação do EntityManager, TransactionManager e etc. Por isso, depois disso apenas crio meus `Repository` e pronto. Como posso fazer com que um `Repository` esteja vinculado a um banco e um segundo a outro banco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, vamos configurar os dados da conexão com os dois bancos de dados no arquivo `application.properties`:

```
#----DATABASE SQLSERVER
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.sqlserver.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.sqlserver.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://****:1433;databaseName=****
spring.sqlserver.datasource.username=****
spring.sqlserver.datasource.password=****

#----DATABASE H2
spring.h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/myh2
spring.h2.datasource.username=sa
spring.h2.datasource.password=
spring.h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Perceba que, diferente da configuração original, foi acrescentado o nome do banco de dados na nomenclatura para diferenciar as conexões. Por fugir da nomenclatura default dos dados de conexão, o Spring Boot não conseguirá iniciar a conexão com os bancos de dados, mas isso será resolvido no passo seguinte.

Depois disso, vamos precisar em nosso pacote `model` criar um subpacote para conter entidades e repositórios de cada banco. Ficaria algo como `...model.h2.entity` e `...model.sqlserver.entity` e o mesmo para o repositório. Óbviamente, você poderá criar da maneira que achar melhor, aqui seria só um exemplo possível de separação.

- br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model

  - h2

    - entity
    - repository
  - sqlserver

    - entity
    - repository

Com essa separação feita, vamos tirar um pouco desse lado automático do Spring Boot para termos mais controle do que está acontecendo e, consequentemente, podermos informar cada pacote ligado a cada banco. Para isso, vamos criar uma classe de configuração para cada banco que estamos lidando:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "h2TransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model.h2.repository" }
)
public class H2Configuration {

    @Bean(name = "h2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.h2.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("h2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model.h2.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("h2PU")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("h2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

E agora um para o SQLServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlServerEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "sqlServerTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model.sqlserver.repository" }
)
public class SqlServerConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sqlServerDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.sqlserver.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sqlServerEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("sqlServerDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model.sqlserver.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("sqlServerPU")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sqlServerTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sqlServerEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

No método de criação do `DataSource`, estamos informando através da *annotation* `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.sqlserver.datasource")` o nome base da conexão com o banco que configuramos no arquivo `application.properties`.

Repare que na *annotation* `@EnableJpaRepositories`, utilizada para informamos detalhes sobre localização dos repositórios e também da conexão, informamos o nome de nosso `EntityManager` e `TransationManager` criado pelos métodos e que também informamos um `basePackage` apontando o pacote de repositórios que relacionados ao banco de dados do caso.

No método de criação do `EntityManagerFactory`, repare que na invocação do método `.packages("br.com.tassioauad.myapp.model.h2.entity")` do `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` estamos informando o pacote em que se localiza nossas entidades relacionadas ao banco específico.

Por fim, é preciso salietar a necessidade de existir a *annotation* `@Primary` nos métodos de pelo menos uma das classes de configuração para informar que é o banco primário ou principal da aplicação. Sendo assim, nada mais é necessário.

Comment: Gostei muito de sua resposta, quais seriam as possibilidades de voce indicar um exemplo de uma aplicação   que usa essa configuração?Usei o spring-boot com 2 databases mas foi usando o jdbc, queria usar com o jpa.. :)

Comment: Tentei usar essa classe mas deu problema no metodo  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("sqlServerDataSource") DataSource dataSource)

Comment: Obrigado. Me ajudou bastante.